# How to use $remote_addr with rails and nginx secure_link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a rails application that makes calls to another server via net::http to retrieve documents.

I have set up Nginx with secure_link.

The nginx config has

```
secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr mySecretCode";
```

On the client side (which is in fact my rails server) I have to create the secure url something like:

```
time = (Time.now + 5.minute).to_i
hmac = Digest::MD5.base64digest("#{time}/#{file_path}#{IP_ADDRESS} mySecretCode").tr("+/","-_").gsub("==",'')
return "#{DOCUMENT_BASE_URL}/#{file_path}?md5=#{hmac}&expires=#{time}"
```

What I want to know is the best way to get the value above for IP_ADDRESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple answers in SO on how to get the ip address but alot of them do not seem as reliable as actually making a request to a web service that returns the ip address of the request as this is what the nginx secure link will see (we don't want some sort of localhost address).

I put the following method on my staging server:

```
  def get_client_ip
    data=Hash.new
    begin
      data[:ip_address]=request.ip
      data[:error]=nil
    rescue Exception =>ex
      data[:error]=ex.message
    end
    render :json=>data
  end
```

I then called the method from the requesting server:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI("myserver.com/web_service/get_client_ip"))
if response.class==Net::HTTPOK
  response_hash=JSON.parse response.body
  ip=response_hash["ip_address"] unless response_hash[:error]
else
  #deal with error
end
```

After getting the ip address successfully I just cached it and did not keep on calling the web service method.